# org babel tangle to extract src code but encounter wrong stingp error

Tags: emacs, org-babel

I tried to extract src code to file with tangle

```
#+name fast_mul.py
#+begin_src ipython :session sicp :results output :tangle ../pySrc/fast_mul.py :exports code 
def fast_mul(a, b):
    if b == 1: return a
    else:
        if even(b): 
            return 2 * fast_mul(a, b//2)
        if odd(b):  return a  + 2 * fast_mul(a, b//2)
def even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0
def odd(n):
    return n % 2 == 1
print(fast_mul(3, 7))
#+end_src
```

but get error report

```
 org-babel-tangle-single-block: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

Alternatively tried

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t :tangle yes
(print 'test)
#+end_src
```

The same error occurred.

What's the problem?

Comment: that looks like it should work, that error can come from `string-match` with a bad argument.  What `org-version` do you have?

Comment: org mode version 9.3 @picklerick

Comment: what do you see in a backtrace (`debug-on-error` => t) when you tangle?  Are you somehow running this from a buffer not associated with a file?  And what function are you calling to tangle, exactly?